# configurable options as radio buttons

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product, custom-options

I'm looking for a solution to show my configurable options as radio buttons instead of select field on a product page for a configurable product.

- show the options
- add class="disabled" for options out of stock
- add class="selected" for chosen option

There are a couple of extensions that solve my issue... partly solve my issue... and most of all provide lot of extra unneeded code.
example: http://www.bullsandbirds.com/sneaker-internationalist-leather-blue-195944

Comment: You can take a look at this: https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher. not exactly what you need, it does not change the selects to radios, but it changes them to labels. But I think you can easily change the label to radio buttons by changing this line: https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/blob/master/js/easylife_switcher/product.js#L148

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this if you use jQuery. It would go in yourtemplate/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml.

Sorry I did not test this but it should get you on the right track.

[here's a fiddle with the jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/N5GYE/)

```
    if ($_product->getStockStatus() == "out of stock"){

    echo "jQuery('select option').each(function () {

    var optValue = jQuery(this).attr('value');
    jQuery('select').before(optValue + ': <input type="radio" name="' + optValue + '" value="' + optValue + '" class="disabled"></br>');

}); //end;"

    }else{

    echo "jQuery('select option').each(function () {

    var optValue = jQuery(this).attr('value');
    jQuery('select').before(optValue + ': <input type="radio" name="' + optValue + '" value="' + optValue + '" class="selected"></br>');

}); //end"

    }
```

Comment: There is no problem to do this with prototype also :-)